# Using variable inside prepared statement line

Tags: php, sql

I'm converting my SQL to prepared statements, but I'm stuck on something. My SQL query is built step by step, so the number of variables are unknown. If I want this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssii', $variable1, $variable2, $variable3, $startpoint, $limit);
```

And I have these two variables:

```
$var1 = "sss"; <Br />
$var2 = "$variable1, $variable2, $variable3";
```

How do I incorporate them in the above string? I tried this, but without the correct result..

```
$stmt->bind_param('{$var1}ii', ".$var2.", $startpoint, $limit);
```

Var 2 is the problem...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it for types like this: `$stmt->bind_param($var1.'ii', ...)` but not for arguments as it's have to be passed by reference. But there is workaround. You can find it in documentation comments: [mysqli-stmt.bind-param](https://www.php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param#104073)

It uses reference class for it:

```
$ref    = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt');
$method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param");
$method->invokeArgs($stmt, $args);
$res->execute();
```

Where `$args` is array with all your types and paramteres. For your example:

```
$args[] = 'sssii';
$args[] = $variable1;
$args[] = $variable2;
(...)
$args[] = $startpoint;
$args[] = $limit;
```

If you have data like this `value1, value2, value3` you can try to `explode` it and `array_merge` with `$args`.

---

```
$foo1 = 'bar1';
$foo2 = 'bar2';
$foo3 = 'bar3';
$foo4 = 'bar4';
$limit = 10;

$stmt->prepare('SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE col1=? AND col2=? AND col3=? AND col4=? LIMIT ?');

$args[] = 'ssssi';
$args[] = $foo1;
$args[] = $foo2;
$args[] = $foo3;
$args[] = $foo4;

$ref    = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt');
$method = $ref->getMethod('bind_param');
$method->invokeArgs($stmt, $args);
$res->execute();
```

Query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE col1="bar1" AND col2="bar2" AND col3="bar3" AND col4="bar4"
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, though I don't fully understand what you mean. I did give me an idea though. I have managed to create an array and with the implod function create a variable ($string) like this: ''sii', $var1, $startpoint, $limit'. However, using $stmt->bind_param($string) still isn't working. Any tips?

Comment: Above you have ready solution for your problem. What part you do not understand? (small edit in example)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double quotes to get variable interpolation.

```
$stmt->bind_param("{$var1}ii", ".$var2.", $startpoint, $limit);
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, it's not var1 that's creating the problem though, it's var2.

Comment: ah.  that's sort of important to the question.  :)